# How to manage the pressure on button on Back for a alert dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I would like to handle the button `onBack` such that when it is depressed, an `AlertDialog` appears, so that the pressure of the onBack button, you set a variable to -1.

This is the code of my alert dialog:

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
{
    switch(id)
    {
      case CUSTOM_DIALOG:        
        AlertDialog.Builder builder1;
        builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(SecondaAttivita.this);       
        builder1.setView(layout);
        builder1.setCancelable(true);
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
                    Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(testo.getWindowToken(), 0);
        testo.setInputType(0);      
        alertDialog1 = builder1.create();       
        break;
      default:
        alertDialog1.dismiss();
        alertDialog1 = null;
    }

    return alertDialog1;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by pressure of the button onBack? you mean when back button pressed?

Comment: when i pressed the default back button of a smartphone.

Answer (score 0):

You can back button event of your smartphone thrugh following code using in your Activity Class

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

        //Action against pressing back button here
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: this method not function for solve my problem. I need to manage the onBack button while my dialog is active

Comment: this works for every case whenever back button pressed.. did you placed it in right place i.e in Activity class outside onCreate() as method of your Activity Class?

Comment: probably not have been clear, after  the alertDialog was opened,  pressing the  onBack must close the alertdialog and set a variable. with the pressure dell'onback,  the alert is closed but I have to handle the closing so you can set a variable

Comment: as far as i understand you are saying that you want if back button is pressed in your app the by a variable you will check that if alert dialog is open then close it and also change variable value so that next time when back is pressed you can check if alert dialog is currently open or not.. so in this case in my code where i commented "//Action against pressing back button here" you will check your variable like its value is 1 which means dialog is currently open so you close dialog here and set variable to 0 and then at code where you oppening this dialog again you will set it to 1 again...